# How to get users last logon from Active Directory

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, vb.net-2010

I am trying to work with active directory to get users information.  For the most part, it's working.  The problem is I cant seem to get a users last logon date.  Anyone have any suggestions?  My code is as follows:

```
    Public Shared Function GetUsersByUsername(ByVal Username As String) As ADUser
    Dim myUser As New ADUser
    Dim oroot As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("GC://ldap.myCompany.com")
    Dim osearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(oroot)
    Dim result As SearchResult

    osearcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(SAMAccountName={0}))", Username)
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName")   'Users login name  
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName")    'Users first name  
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")   'Users last name  
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")   'Email address       
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("accountExpires") 'expiration date

    result = osearcher.FindOne
    Try
        Dim userPath As String() = result.Path.ToString.Split(New Char() {","c})
        Dim parsedString As String
        Dim User As DirectoryEntry
        Dim expirationDate As String

        User = result.GetDirectoryEntry()

        myUser.UserID = result.Properties("cn").Item(0)
        myUser.EmailAddress = result.Properties("mail").Item(0)
        myUser.FirstName = result.Properties("givenName").Item(0)
        myUser.LastName = result.Properties("sn").Item(0)         

        expirationDate = result.Properties("accountExpires").Item(0)

        If (isAccountLocked(User) = True) Then
            myUser.Status = ADUser.AccountStatus.Locked
        ElseIf (isAccountEnabled(User) = False) Then
            myUser.Status = ADUser.AccountStatus.Disabled
        ElseIf (isAccountExpired(expirationDate) = True) Then
            myUser.Status = ADUser.AccountStatus.Expired
        Else
            myUser.Status = ADUser.AccountStatus.Active
        End If

        parsedString = userPath((userPath.Length - 3))
        myUser.Domain = parsedString.Substring(3, parsedString.Length - 3)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

    Return myUser
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

works for me:

1. Load the property:

   ```
   osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogon")
   ```
2. Access it:

   ```
   dim myDateInterval = result.Properties("lastLogon").Item(0)
   ```

Note you'll get back an interval value.  It's 64-bit, unsigned, I think.  There are some casting methods in .NET, but they only take signed 64-bit.  Haven't checked how many years ahead that would be before it was an issue!

Also, if you use the newer UserPrincipal from DirectoryServices then it's got lastlogon in it, that returns a nullable date.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'lastLogon' LDAP attribute? Your code looks good, I'm guessing you're just not sure where the information is stored in AD?

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark.  I am new to using AD, so I'm not exactly sure of what I'm doing lol.  It's been mostly up hill.  Any way, I've tried the lastLogon attribute but it always comes back null.  I know it should have a value because I test with my account, which is logged into everyday.

Comment: I've done LDAP stuff a few years ago for an internal telephone directory and it was a bit of a nuisance; this guy's site is really useful and he has some info on why lastLogon might not be working for you: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine85.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link but I don't think it will help.  I've tried using "result.Properties("lastLogon").Item(0)  " but it always comes back null